# How to use sitemap gemerator extention in vs code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, sitemap

I use sitemap generator extention in vs code to generate a sitemap for my website code in vs code,  It works find but no url path for the sitemap was generated,  pls how can I generate the url

I tried vs code sitemap generator extention to generate a sitemap ,  sitemap.xml was generated without sitemap url,  how can i create sitemap url together with sitemap.xml file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the `sitemap.json` file in your project.
2. Add the URLs in the sitemap to the `urls` array, for example:

```json
{
  "url": "url1/what/you/want/to/add",
  "priority": 0.8,
  "changefreq": "daily"
},
{
  "url": "url2/what/you/want/to/add",
  "priority": 0.6,
  "changefreq": "weekly"
}
```